# taking the diagonal limit

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I've gotten rusty with a lot of these arguments... Could someone help me verify (or unverify) this?

If 
$$\lim_{n} \lim_{k} f_{n}(x_{k}) = \lim_{k} \lim_{n} f_{n}(x_{k})$$

can we take the diagonal sequence  $ f_{n}(x_{n}) $ and say

$$\lim_{n} f_{n}(x_{n}) = \lim_{k} \lim_{n} f_{n}(x_{k})$$

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No : suppose that $f_n(x_n) = 1$ and $0$ elsewhere. Then

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \lim_{k\to \infty} f_{n}(x_{k}) = \lim_{k\to \infty} \lim_{n\to \infty} f_{n}(x_{k}) = 0$$

but

$$\lim_{n} f_{n}(x_{n}) = 1$$

Comment: Nice counter example! However, I think if $f_n$s be continuous and $\{x_n\}_{n\in{\mathbb N}}$ be convergent, the claim is true!

Comment: No, you need stronger hypothesis. Suppose that the function $f_n$ is equal to $0$ on $[\frac{1}{n},1]$ and is a triangle with height $1$ on $[0,\frac{2}{n}]$ (with the top at 1/n). let $x_n = 1/n$. It verify the hypothesis : $$\lim_{k} \lim_n f_n(x_k) = 0 $$  $$\lim_{n} \lim_k f_n(x_k) = f(0)=0 $$ But you have $f_n(x_n)=1$

Comment: Thanks a lot. In my special situation (I've abstracted the issue into here), I have a uniformly convergent sequence of analytic functions on some compact set E. Anyway to get the diagonal sequence? What extra hypotheses would be necessary?

Comment: With these hypothesis, it should work. Let's call $f$ the limit of $f_n$. Both $f_n$ and $f$ are absolutly continuous, because E is compact and the convergence is uniform. Then for $\forall \epsilon>0$, for n and k big enough, we have $$|f_n(x_n)-f(x)| = |f_n(x_n)-f_n(x_k)+f_n(x_k)-f(x_k)+f(x_k)-f(x)| $$ $$\leq |f_n(x_n)-f_n(x_k)|+|f_n(x_k)-f(x_k)|+|f(x_k)-f(x)|\leq 3 \epsilon $$ Hence $\lim_n f_n(x_n) = f(x)$. And it's easy to show that we also get $\lim_k \lim_n f_n(x_k) = f(x)$ and $\lim_n \lim_k f_n(x_k) = f(x)$.

Comment: Perfect! thanks a lot

Comment: @Tryss for anybody tuning in.. I think the condition we need for the first term |$f_{n}(x_{n}) - f_{n}(x_{k})$| $ \leq e$ is equicontinuity of the normal family F, which is guaranteed by Arzela Ascoli.